# DHTML Menu not displaying in other environments

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, dhtml

This is going to be a bit confusing, but I have a client that is going to be using another organization for their Job Application portal within their website.  Currently, they have an old fashion DHTML drop menu displayed for their main navigation.  However, with an exact replica template created by the other organization housing their Job Application product within an iframe, the drop menu is not being populated.

**Working drop menus:** http://www.shawmut.com/join_us/index.cfm

**Job Application portal without working menus:** https://careers-shawmut.icims.com/jobs/intro?amp%3Bbranding=test&amp%3Bhashed=0&branding=test

I'm going to make an assumption and blame the issue on the server loading the JavaScript files at incorrect times, preventing it from producing the menus in the HTML (at the bottom of the body) and in turn allowing the JavaScript to change the visibility of the menus from hidden to visible upon mouse hover.

**The core JavaScript and HTML with comments:** http://www.shawmut.com/drop-menu.txt

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I'm unable to find out why the menus don't work within the Job Application portal environment.  I will provide **upvotes** and a **check-mark** to anyone providing an answer for any help or advice given, thanks!

Comment: Here is another example of me getting it to work in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jodriscoll/cTeV5/

Comment: Even if I forcefully place the HTML created by the JavaScript at the bottom right before </body>, It still does not communicate with the JavaScript to toggle the visibility of the menus when you hover over.  I'm going to assume that the entire JavaScript associated with this menu is being loaded too early.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, I tried to use the "defer" tag for the script on all the scripts associated with this menu.  Unfortunately, that did not work as well.

Comment: @Natalia - I saw your help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925354/js-code-not-working-because-of-bad-placement, could you help with this issue too?

Comment: I've also tried placing the JavaScript files that produce this menu at the bottom of the <body> without any fix.